# Hero animation with an AlertDialog

Tags: dart, flutter

I'd like to implement a hero animation for an image on my main screen while presenting an AlertDialog widget with the same image in the dialog's content.

I'd like the presentation to appear as in the screenshot below. When I tap the image in the bottom left, I'd like the hero animation and an inset preview of the image along with a transparent overlay that can be tapped to dismiss.

[image]

The below code doesn't perform the hero animation.

```
class AlertDialogTest extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Material(
      child: new InkWell(
        child: new Hero(
          tag: "preview",
          child: new Container(
            alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomLeft,
            child: new Image(
              image: new AssetImage('assets/images/theater.png'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            child: new AlertDialog(
              content: new Hero(
                tag: "preview",
                child: new Image(
                  image: new AssetImage('assets/images/theater.png'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Hero transitions are only enabled for transitions between two instances of `PageRoute`. So if you want to make use of the existing `Hero` system, you should probably use a `PageRoute`.

Instead of pushing an `AlertDialog`, you could try a full-screen dialog:

```
Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
  fullscreenDialog: true,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Dialog'),
      ),
      body: new Hero(
        tag: "preview",
        child: new Image(
          image: new AssetImage('assets/images/theater.png'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
));
```

If you want a semi-transparent barrier, you can extend `PageRoute` and make it a more dialog-like.

[image: video]

Here is some code that implements the animation above.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HeroDialogRoute<T> extends PageRoute<T> {
  HeroDialogRoute({ this.builder }) : super();

  final WidgetBuilder builder;

  @override
  bool get opaque => false;

  @override
  bool get barrierDismissible => true;

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => const Duration(milliseconds: 300);

  @override
  bool get maintainState => true;

  @override
  Color get barrierColor => Colors.black54;

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    return new FadeTransition(
      opacity: new CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animation,
        curve: Curves.easeOut
      ),
      child: child
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    return builder(context);
  }

}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Hero demo'),
      ),
      body: new Align(
        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
        child: new Card(
          child: new Hero(
            tag: 'developer-hero',
            child: new Container(
              width: 300.0,
              height: 300.0,
              child: new FlutterLogo(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.developer_mode),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            new HeroDialogRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return new Center(
                  child: new AlertDialog(
                    title: new Text('You are my hero.'),
                    content: new Container(
                      child: new Hero(
                        tag: 'developer-hero',
                        child: new Container(
                          height: 200.0,
                          width: 200.0,
                          child: new FlutterLogo(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      new FlatButton(
                        child: new Text('RAD!'),
                        onPressed: Navigator
                          .of(context)
                          .pop,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Depending on the dialog size and where your hero is located, you might be able to see the original `Hero` reappear underneath the dialog once the second `Hero` has finished animating into position. If this bothers you, you could stack two copies the image, with only the top one being a `Hero`, or you could trigger an animation to hide the original `Hero` (perhaps using `AnimatedCrossFade`) until the dialog is closed.

Another option is that you could implement the animation yourself, instead of using the existing `Hero` system. You'd probably want to read up on the [animations documentation](https://flutter.io/animations/) and possibly copy bits and pieces of [heroes.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/heroes.dart).

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my post and added a screenshot of the presentation I'm aiming for. I'm unsure of how to edit your sample to include a transparent overlay or if that's even possible.

Comment: Edited my answer to explain how to do it with a semitransparent overlay. It's a bit tricky because you might be able to see both Heroes at the same time!

Comment: Works perfectly! One small typo in HeroDialogRoute: barrierDismissable -> barrierDismissible. Thanks!

Comment: I fixed the typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

You can use a `PageRouteBuilder`. As mentioned by others, dialogs don't work with Heroes, only PageRoutes do.

Replace your `onTap()` code with this:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
    new PageRouteBuilder(
        opaque: false,
        barrierDismissible:true,
        pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
            return Container(
                child: Hero(
                    tag: "preview",
                    child: new Image(
                        image: new AssetImage('assets/images/theater.png'),
                    ),
                ),
            );
        }
    )
)
```

[Here](https://github.com/nirav4273/flutter_sliverappbar) is a demo.

Comment: This is a WAY SIMPLE solution

Comment: hi I'm using your code to open alert box. It open perfectly but it hitting api multiple times

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede Heros might be built several times before, during and after the transition, so take care that your api call is not within your build method

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with a ModalBottomSheet instead of AlertDialog?