# how to show a widget like a popup

Tags: flutter

Currently, I have a grid view. When I tap it, I navigate to another page using a hero widget.

On that page, I just have a container that shows information about that grid tile.

What I want is to have that container come on top of the grid view instead of being a different page.

How can I pop it like that? And if possible I'd rather keep the hero animation.
[image: the grid]

[image: the container]

Comment: a `PopupRoute`? the docs say: *"A modal route that overlays a widget over the current route.*" - this is unlike the "normal" `PageRoute` that is documented as *"A modal route that replaces the entire screen."*

Comment: This seems like the intended way. But after some trial-error, I got some problems with my providers so I'll try the other approaches.

Comment: Apparently that doesn't work with popup route and I need to override popuproute to create a custom route and call it using onRouteGenerator property of the MaterialWidget. Then, the providers get mixed up and I get a bunch of errors.

Comment: ok, forget it, `Hero` docs says that it works with `PageRoute` only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am posting what I ended up doing because it works.

What @Nonstapp and @Parth suggested works except for the Hero transition since it applies to PageRoutes only.

Therefore I found another way of showing a similar popup with a PageRoute.

The information widget that I am displaying:

```
return Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 8,
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 8,
      0),
  child: Material(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    child: ...
```

The padding obviously is for positioning and the Material widget is to give it Material style and enabled widgets like IconButton. Give the Material widget a transparent color.

This is how I call it:

```
void seeDetails(BuildContext context, Book book) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      PageRouteBuilder(
        fullscreenDialog: true,
        opaque: false,
        pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: book,
          child: DetailCard(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I use the PageRouter to show a fullscreen dialog but due to my settings up there, only the information card is visible.

The downside is that I cannot enable barrierDismissiblesince I am on another route atm.

This is my result:

[image: result]

However, the real solution is what @pskink suggested above. It requires more setup and adjustments and I had problems with Providers. [Here is how you can implement it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44404763/14037074)

Answer (score 1):

You should use showDialog method, like this:

```
InkWell(
 child: GridItem(),
 onTap: () {
  showDialog(
   context: context,
     builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
      content: Hero(child: Card(child: YourWidget()))
     ); // you can use SimpleDialog, specify barrier dismissible etc
 },
)
```

Here is the link about dialog class
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Dialog-class.html

About the Hero I'm not sure, cause I write it like from head, but it should do the trick (ofc append the same tag, you don't need the Card parent if your widget already got one - Hero requires a Material widget)

Comment: this works but I cannot use Hero because it requires a page transition.

Comment: I see, I'm glad that you've found the solution

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom dialog:-

```
onPressed: () {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) => Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Show dialog"),
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return Dialog(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
                    elevation: 16,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 400.0,
                      width: 360.0,
                      child: ListView(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(height: 20),
                          Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "Leaderboard",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 20),
                          _buildName(imageAsset: 'assets/chocolate.jpg', name: "Name 1", score: 1000),
                          _buildName(imageAsset: 'assets/chocolate.jpg', name: "Name 2", score: 2000),
                          _buildName(imageAsset: 'assets/chocolate.jpg', name: "Name 3", score: 3000),
                          _buildName(imageAsset: 'assets/chocolate.jpg', name: "Name 4", score: 4000),
                          _buildName(imageAsset: 'assets/chocolate.jpg', name: "Name 5", score: 5000),
                          _buildName(imageAsset: 'assets/chocolate.jpg', name: "Name 6", score: 6000),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        );
    }
    
    
    Widget _buildName({String imageAsset, String name, double score}) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 12),
            Container(height: 2, color: Colors.redAccent),
            SizedBox(height: 12),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage(imageAsset),
                  radius: 30,
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 12),
                Text(name),
                Spacer(),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 20),
                  child: Text("${score}"),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.yellow[900],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
```